# Describe the group of all linear transformations of $\mathbf R^{2+}$ that preserve oriented area

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-transformations

$\text{SL}(2,\mathbf R)$ is the group of all linear transformations of $\mathbf R^2$ that preserve oriented area.

> What is a description of the group of all linear transformations of $\mathbf R^{2+}$ that preserve oriented area?

For example a description of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbf R)$ is:

$$\mbox{SL}(2,\mathbf{R}) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \colon a,b,c,d\in\mathbf{R}\mbox{ and }ad-bc=1\right\}.$$

The group of all linear transformations of $\mathbf R^{2+}$ that preserve oriented area is isomorphic to $\text{SL}(2,\mathbf R).$ I'm not sure how to describe its elements though.

A linear mapping* $F:\mathbf R^2\to \mathbf R^{2+}$ with $F(x,y)=(e^x,e^y)$ transports the vector space/group structure from $\mathbf R^2$ to $\mathbf R^{2+}$ where we now have $1$ acting as the zero vector.

In one dim. addition in $\mathbf R$ i.e. $a\oplus b$ extends to $a * b$ in $\mathbf R^{+}.$ Scalar multiplication in $\mathbf R$ i.e. $\gamma b$ extends to $b^{\gamma}$ in $\mathbf R^+.$

*We can view $F$ as a linear mapping having showed that $F$ is a map between two vector spaces. And $\mathbf R^+$ can be seen as the image of $\mathbf R$ under $F(x)=(e^x).$

Obviously the $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf R^+$ settings I've described are equivalent representations. The question is how to *translate the information* under the linear map $F$ to get the analogous group elements.

So, back to the question: What is a description of the group of all linear transformations of $\mathbf R^{2+}$ that preserve oriented area?

I think the group elements must be $2 \times 2$ matrices but I can't figure out the entries or properties of these matrices.

Or maybe I've been thinking about it wrong. Maybe oriented area cannot be preserved under the linear group isomorphism $F,$ because it's not an isometry. I suppose the question is to offer a description of the group $G$ where $F:\text{SL}(2,\mathbf R) \to G.$

Hopefully this isn't too long and confusing.

Comment: How is ${\bf R}^{2+}$ different from ${\bf R}^2$? Also ${\rm SL}(2,{\bf R})$ isn't just *isomorphic* to the group of relevant linear transformations, it **is** the group of orientation and area-preserving linear transformations...

Comment: @runway44 $\mathbf R^{2+}$ is the positive first quadrant

Comment: Well, any such linear transformation would have to turn the unit square into a unit rectangle, so the only area-preserving and orientation-preserving mappings that preserve the first quadrant are squeeze mappings, i.e. diagonal elements of ${\rm SL}(2,{\bf R})$. But this is a 1D abelian subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,{\bf R})$, whereas ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$ itself is 3D and nonabelian, so they are *not* isomorphic like you claim.

Comment: @runway44 I edited the post and hopefully you can see more of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: just tried to add more of my thought process, and attempts to work through the problem.

Comment: You've described ${\bf R}^{2+}$ as a 2D vector space, but you haven't defined how area is defined. If you're just talking about the usual measure, treating ${\bf R}^{2+}$ as a subset of ${\bf R}^2$, then I don't think there are any nontrivial linear area-preserving maps. But if you want to define area on ${\bf R}^{2+}$ a different way, so that your isomorphism $F:{\bf R}^2\to{\bf R}^{2+}$ is an isometry, then you're just talking about **transport of structure**, and your group of isometries is just ${\rm SL}(2,{\bf R})$ conjugated by $F$.

Comment: If you work this out, you should arrive at the conclusion that this action of ${\rm SL}(2,{\bf R})$ on ${\bf R}^{2+}$ is defined by the formula $[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}](x,y)=(x^ay^b,x^cy^d)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121304/discussion-between-geocalc33-and-runway44).